# PowerBI, show item numbers but still calculate run rate off of a group code

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Kind of difficult to explain, but I have a table that totals the Days on hand by taking the trailing twelve months (TTM) sold and divides it out by 365 to get a product sold per day.

This works great when I apply it to my PRODUCT GROUP CODE to see how the TTM works for these products sans product specifications, but when I add this TTM Sold to my SKU table it does it by individual sku which does not give me a complete picture.

Is there a way to Calculate my TTM SOLD only by PRODUCT GROUP CODE even though its brought into my ITEM CODE or SKU table? So, the equation below but always done to the PRODUCT GROUP CODE level?

```
TTM SOLD =
CALCULATE (
    'Sales Invoice Transactions'[Sales Invoice Quantity],
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Date'[Date], LASTDATE ( 'Date'[Date] ), -12, MONTH )
)
```

I changed it to say REMOVEFILTERS or ALLEXCEPT but these keep resulting in a total of TTM SOLD across the entire company.

```
TTM SOLD = 
CALCULATE (
    'Sales Invoice Transactions'[Sales Invoice Quantity], 
    DATESINPERIOD( 'Date'[Date], LASTDATE( 'Date'[Date]), -12, MONTH), 
    ALLEXCEPT(PRODUCTGROUPCODE)
)
```

Hard to provide sales data but if each specific product or sku has a group and I average sales for the last three months by product group I get what I want when I add this variable into PowerBI, but when I put this into a list per sku then it only averages the sales based on specific sku. I want it to keep the average based on the product group as a whole:

Product Group   |Sku    |Sales Data Jan |Sales Data Feb |Sales Data March

Caps             Cap1             2          1                 1

Caps             Cap2             5          4                 5

Caps             Cap3             6          5                 4

Screws           Screw1           3          2                 3

Screws           Screw2           2          3                 2

Boxes            Box1             5          4                 5

Comment: Your second bit of code appears to not be valid DAX. I suggest adding sample data and desired outcome if you want someone to take a look at your issue.

Comment: its dax in PowerBI

Comment: `ALLEXCEPT` requires at least two arguments. So it does not appear to be valid DAX, no.

Comment: oh, I think there is a comma after it, but either way it didn't work.